# how to center a button in kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy, position, center

**Hi I'm making an app but there's an issue occurring. There are 2 buttons each on different screens. How do I center both buttons?
1st button is in MainWindow and 2nd button is in ImportWindow.
Please check my code.
Both buttons displaying at (0,0) position. I want to set the position in the center.**

this is .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class ImportWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MySplashScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(ImportWindow(name='second'))
        return sm
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MySplashScreenApp().run()
```

and this is .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    ImportWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    Button:
        text: "Start"
        font_size: 12
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: 100, 100
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "second"
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'


<ImportWindow>:
    Button:
        text: "Import"
        font_size: 12
        size: 75, 50
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: 100, 100
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Comment: Have a look at [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint).

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've tried but it's not working

Comment: Please update your question to show what you tried.

Comment: @JohnAnderson please check

Comment: @JohnAnderson your given line of code worked but only for the second button i.e Import button. But it is not working for the 1st button i.e start button. :(

Comment: Update your post to show what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `pos_hint` is incorrect.  As shown in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint), the `pos_hint` is a dictionary. in order to center a widget using `pos_hint`, you can use:

```
pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
```